# How to fix Javascript function so my message pops up

Tags: javascript, function, dom-events

I am working on a lesson for homework and this is the only function that isn't working. The message in the function(event) will not show up on the screen. Thanks.

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (event) {
    return 'You have changes that have not been saved...';
}, false);
```

I expect the event to fire when I type something in the textbox and try reloading the page.

Comment: It does fire, but your function is just returning a string. It's neither preventing the default behaviour *(namely the page unload that is in progress when this event fires)* nor does it do anything that would add this string to the DOM or to show it in an alert box.

Comment: @Thomas Okay, thanks for getting back so fast. How would I show this in the alert box? I tried adding alert('You have changes that have not been saved...') in the function(event) code block but it didn't seem to work

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend reading the [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event) documentation regarding this, according to the documentation you need to call the `preventDefault()` method to have an alert show up.

for example:

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', (event) => {
  // Cancel the event as stated by the standard.
  event.preventDefault();
  // Chrome requires returnValue to be set.
  event.returnValue = '';
});
```

However it does work without calling the `preventDefault()` method because the documentation states that this is not supported by all browsers.

Some browsers instead require you to either assign a string to the events `returnValue` property or return a string from the event handler.

In your case also I would return a blank string like this `event.returnValue = '';` the reason being that custom strings were supported however this is now deprecated and not available in most browsers.

In conclusion I strongly recommend reading the [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event) documentation and using the example code block above, depending on your browser you should keep or remove `event.preventDefault();`